# SQL Query to return multiple data from inner join

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join, union

I have two database table, one is registerd user table and the other one is chat message table.
 I want to list users that have conversion in chat message table. The below sql query does it but it show the 
 active user name as on the list instead of the party user.

## Table users_account

```
reg_userid | Name
--------------------------
1          | Peter   
2          | John
```

### Table chatroom_message

```
userid_a | userid_b
--------------------------
1          | 2   
3          | 1
```

### SQL

```
SELECT * FROM chatroom_message cm
INNER JOIN users_account ua ON cm.userid_a = ua.reg_userid 
WHERE cm.userid_a = :chat_client
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM chatroom_message cm
INNER JOIN users_account ua ON cm.userid_b = ua.reg_userid 
WHERE cm.userid_b = :chat_client
```

Current Session User Id = `1 (Peter)`, so when i run above sql query it return below table

### Resault

```
reg_userid | Name
--------------------------
1          | Peter
```

My problem is how do i run an sql query to check if the active user is in chat message `userid_a OR userid_b`
If the result is found let it return the name of the chat party which is `John`, as his contact chat list, same goes to `John`
When he login the result will also show him `Peter` not his own now

I want my result be John login to his account the name of Peter will show as his chat partner.

```
reg_userid | Name
--------------------------
1          | Peter
```

I want my result be Peter login to his account the name of John will show as his chat partner.

```
reg_userid | Name
--------------------------
2          | John
```

Comment: could you please post expected result for your data?

Comment: @RadimBača i have updated my question

Comment: whit "active user"  you mean the value you assign to _chat_client ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are almost there. This is probably what you are looking for:

```
SELECT ua.reg_userid, ua.name FROM chatroom_message cm
INNER JOIN users_account ua ON cm.userid_b = ua.reg_userid 
WHERE cm.userid_a = :chat_client
UNION ALL
SELECT ua.reg_userid, ua.name  FROM chatroom_message cm
INNER JOIN users_account ua ON cm.userid_a = ua.reg_userid 
WHERE cm.userid_b = :chat_client
```

Comment: Your answer worked, but the alias SELECT `ua` didn't work until i put the full table name

Answer (score 0):

I think this command can serve you

```
SELECT cm.*, 
      ua.reg_userid, ua.Name ,
      ua2.reg_userid, ua2.Name
   FROM chatroom_message cm
          INNER JOIN users_account ua 
                  ON cm.userid_a = ua.reg_userid 
          INNER JOIN users_account ua2 
                  ON cm.userid_b = ua2.reg_userid
    WHERE cm.userid_a = :chat_client
```

**[[demo]](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/476f8f/1)**

Comment: I tried ruining your query it worked but in on account i have two chat users only on user showed

Comment: Add the command at finished     OR cm.userid_b = :chat_client